# Vim, installing pathogen Windows

Tags: windows, vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree, pathogen

I tried to install vim plugin on my Windows OS but it don't work. 
fist I'm going to show you my vim directoris architecture then to show you my _vimrc.vim file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim >

17/07/2017  16:15    <DIR>          vim80
17/07/2017  17:45    <DIR>          vimfiles
17/07/2017  17:50               200 _vimrc
```

inside vim80 no changes added.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles

17/07/2017  17:47    <DIR>          autoload
17/07/2017  16:52    <DIR>          bundle
17/07/2017  17:05    <DIR>          config
17/07/2017  16:42    <DIR>          plugin
```

And this is how look like my ./vimfiles directorie
Inside I created 4 directorie first one: ./autoload for the pathogen symlink,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\autoload

17/07/2017  17:12    <SYMLINK>      pathogen.vim [C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\pathogen\autoload\pathogen.vim]
```

As you see pathogen plugin is inside ./plugin/pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim
Then I creat a ./bundle directories for all the other plugins like NERDTree :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\bundle

17/07/2017  16:52    <DIR>          nerdtree
```

Then this is my vimrc.vim file:

```
set nocompatible

" Initialisation de pathogen:
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

runtime! $VIM/vimfiles/config/**/*.vim
```

I don't know why but when I try to use `:NERDTree` this message appear:

```
E492: Unknow command line :NERDTree
```

Please if someone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim` belongs to your system, not to you. You are supposed to customize Vim in `%userprofile%\vimfiles`.

Comment: Thanks for reading me,  however I'm not sure this is the cause of my problem.

Comment: It is the root cause of your problem. Return that directory to its pristine state and do your config where you are supposed to do it.

Comment: Hey, as you say I change the location of the vimfiles folder to C:/Users/Username/. In an other way the reason why my other architectur didn't work was I havn't remove the _vimrc.vim file from my C:/Users/Username/ folder. But I have an other mistake see under.

Answer (score 2):

Move pathogen

from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\pathogen\autoload\pathogen.vim`

to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim`

(I removed plugin/pathogen)

Because you installed pathogen as a 'normal' pluggin so that pathogen can find it but patogen must be directly copied as a vim extension: it is a package manager itself so must be loaded the old way.

Answer (score 0):

So I move all the vimfiles folder and the `_vimrc` file in my `C:/Users/Username` directorie and nothing in my architectur change (see comments of the previous post). I also change the `_vimrc` contents with:

```
set nocompatible
set nocp

" Initialisation de pathogen:
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

source $HOME\vimfiles\config\settings.vim
```

But I have an other mistake. when I'm launching Gvim this message appear:

```
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
```

I dont know why, this is the result of `:scriptname` :

```
  1: ~\_vimrc
  2: ~\vimfiles\config\settings.vim
  3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syntax.vim
  4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\synload.vim
  5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\syncolor.vim
  6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\filetype.vim
  7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\menu.vim
  8: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\lang\menu_fr.latin1.vim
  9: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\lang\menu_fr_fr.latin1.vim
 10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload\paste.vim
 11: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin.vim
 12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent.vim
 13: ~\vimfiles\plugin\pathogen\autoload\pathogen.vim
 14: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
 15: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\gzip.vim
 16: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\logiPat.vim
 17: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\manpager.vim
 18: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\matchparen.vim
 19: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
 20: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\rrhelper.vim
 21: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\spellfile.vim
 22: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
 23: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\tohtml.vim
 24: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
 25: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
 26: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\scripts.vim
 27: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\syntax\vim.vim
 28: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\ftplugin\vim.vim
 29: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\indent\vim.vim
 30: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\autoload\vimball.vim
```

I try a lot of solution from forum but no one work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just resolving my mistake,
so this is my vim :

```
set nocompatible
set nocp

filetype off

" Initialisation de pathogen:
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on

source $HOME\vimfiles\config\settings.vim
```

Then dont use symlink they don't work, use only file

```
    18/07/2017  12:15    <SYMLINK>      pathogen [C:\Users\Usename\vimfiles\plugin\pathogen\autoload\pathogen.vim]
    18/07/2017  11:13                   pathogen.vim
```

You need to update pathogen manualy.